# Audit logging on users and roles in office 365 Admin console

Tags: office-365, auditing

I would like to know the way on how to extract the logs for user addition/deletion changes and role based changes in office 365. I am the global admin to my tenant but one of the global admin has removed the global admin role of few other users. I would like to investigate the issue via auditing and reporting.

Kindly guide me on this.

Comment: I've found some good tips on Exchange online auditing in this blog [post](http://howdoicomputer.com/2016/05/exchange-online-and-hybrid-exchange-auditing-configurations/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is unattainable as all global admins have the same permission. What you can do is to raise a customer support ticket to Microsoft in the Office 365 portal, they can help you trace which global admin who stripped off your other global admins.

More info [here](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/241014)